# Why can't some CSS Classes not be overwritten in the Component styling but others can?

Tags: angular

Why is it, that when using packages, I can sometimes overwrite css classes for some components but can't for other cases?

For example in the material package, I can't use this in my component styling to override the class:

```
.mat-tab-header{
    background-color: #424242;
}
```

but this works in the component styling:

```
.mat-card {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I know I can set the styling in the global `styles.scss` or set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. I just want to understand why it's not working? What can be the difference between these css classes? I would really like some explanation to this.

Comment: The second one seems to be an element instead as it doesn't start with a `.`

Comment: @cyberpirate92 yup, thats a copy and paste error but the issue is the same

Answer (score 0):

Angular adds the unique attribute on every component and his template tags.

You can inspect the element and see.

Every component will have a unique attribute with the prefix `_nghost` something like this `_nghost-{unique-name}`. And every tag in the component will have the attribute with the name `_ngcontent-{unique-name}`.
The class which is declared into `component.css` file will have the name `.class[_ngcontent-{unique-name}]` instead of `.class` and that is why the class which is declared in the `component.css` file can't manipulate with tags that are placed in other components.

the same thing happens with the `mat-card` element.

you can inspect the element and see the `mat-card` have the component unique attribute name.
[image]

[image]